# What is an expression for "getting older in appearance"?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, expression-choice, idiom-requests

> "The children in school grew up so fast. They, like their parents,
>   went about their professional career. In a flash they became gray and
>   grizzled, and were getting tired of life."

Is there a better expression than "*gray and grizzled*"? I want to express the subject's appearance getting older, their skin with more and more wrinkles, their face with increasing spots, and hair turning gray. **Is there an expression or word that would vividly depict this feeling of "getting older in appearance"?**

Comment: Try "graying" in place of "getting older in appearance."

Comment: Writing advice? And in a wink of an eye their taut supple skins lost their youthful glow, their eyes grew smaller and duller, their hair greyer and thinner etc etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of different words that could do the trick. The most common being "to age":

> to become old or older
>   http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/age

There's olden: 
Def. 1) intr. To grow old, to become old in appearance or character, to age

Def 2) trans. To cause to grow old, to make older in appearance or character, to age
Source: OED2

There's veterate: "To wax [become] old"

and the adjective veterascent: "Growing old"
Source: OED2

Finally, if you're looking for a word that means deteriorate with age you can look at senesce: "(Of a living organism) deteriorate with age"
Source: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/senesce

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the idea of @Mari-Lou A's comment - sorry, can't yet comment myself - that you'd get the best imagery with details about the subject's appearance, as you've already done in your question.  I can picture the people being like **overripe, decomposing fruit**, which is my suggestion if you want a simile.

For a word, I also suggest

> **timeworn** - [showing the effects of age or antiquity](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/timeworn)

Answer (score 1):

***[Wizened](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wizen)***, "to become dry, shrunken, and wrinkled often as a result of aging or of failing vitality."

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is *[decrepit](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decrepit)*, meaning "wasted and weakened by or as if by the infirmities of old age."

Answer (score 1):

[hoary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hoary)

By Dr. Strange's "hoary hosts of Hoggoth":

Gray, old and gray, covered in gray and white hairs.

Answer (score 0):

> In a flash they became gray and saggy

OR

> gray and sagging

Comment: idiots downvted this, it is now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

*wrinkled*

> In a flash they became gray and wrinkled

Answer (score -3):

from MIB III, you got some city miles on you!